# Problem in setting an IP address on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: ethernet, ip

I'm trying to set an IP address on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, Settings>Network. I expect that, after clicking "apply", under the lines highlighted in the terminal the result of my operation will appear but it is not. I say those lines because the hardware address where I'm setting is 9C: EB: E8: 2D: 68: 8C. I perform all these operations with the ethernet cable attached to the device that interests me,
[Artix-7 35T Arty FPGA](https://www.xilinx.com/products/boards-and-kits/arty.html). I have tried both with automatic DNS and not.

[image]

Comment: do you restarted network service?

Comment: Are you trying to set up an ad-hoc, that is, device-to-device connection with the Artix? I'm not sure Network Manager is the way to do so.

Comment: You can't set the address to the same address as the gateway.

Answer (score 1):

That means the ip address 10.10.10.1 is not available.

Ping and find out the address you are choosing is available.

If any ip address is available for use, ping will return "Destination Host Unreachable."

Comment: If I run $ ping 10.10.10.1, it does not go well but I realized that after changing the settings of my laptop network card, then after the ping works

Comment: Better use some address like 192.168.0.241 and default gateway as 192.168.0.71. But before that check the availability of the ip address.